# Gravitational waves and EOS in neutron stars

Tags: astrophysics, gravitational-waves, neutron-stars

What is/are the gravitational wave observable/s that makes possible to measure the parameter/s of the equation of state of neutron stars?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of them:

1. Tidal deformability $\Lambda$ $\rightarrow$ information about low density behavior of EoS
2. Radius R $\rightarrow$ (through Bayesian analysis) show correlation with the slope parameter $L$ of nuclear matter
3. Mass M $\rightarrow$ implies a mass that has to be reached by the M-R curves which can be evaluated via TOV equations and use the EoS $\rightarrow$ constrain the used EoSs
4. Cooling behavior of neutron stars $\rightarrow$ inner composition
5. Moment of Inertia (if measurable)
6. Radial Oscillations, etc.

- some more

(only 1,2,3,5,6 can be derived from GW data and not always as there is some degeneracy left usually)